# create a tridiagonal matrix with other matrices in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, diagonal

I have an algorithm that creates random `nxn`-matrices `A(i,j)` and now I want this matrices in a tridiagonal shape:

```
A(1,1) A(1,2)  0       0      0
A(2,1) A(2,2) A(2,3)   0      0
  0    A(3,2) A(3,3) A(3,4)   0
  0      0    A(4,3) A(4,4) A(4,5)
```

And so on.

I tried the commands `diag` and `tridiag` but both are just working for integers.

**EDIT**
I will explain my problem with an example:
I create different random `3x3`matrices:

```
a=randi(10,3);
b=randi(10,3);
...
k=randi(10,3)
```

And now I want to create a big tridiagonal matrix `L` where the random matrices `a,...,k` are on the sub-, super- and diagonal line:

```
L= a b 0 0 0
   c d e 0 0
   0 f g h 0
   0 0 i j k
```

Comment: Did any of the approaches in the solutions posted here work for you?

Comment: Now each `a,b,..k` in `3x3`, which element of them should be put in `L`?

Comment: all nine elements of every matrix `a,b,...,k` have to be in `L`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want to keep both [subdiagonal](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Subdiagonal.html) and [superdiagonal](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Superdiagonal.html) elements in there alongwith the diagonal ones.

**Approach #1**

First approach could be with `bsxfun` there for a generic m x n sized matrix -

```
[m,n] = size(A); %// get size
Aout = A.*( bsxfun(@le,[0:m-1]',1:n) & bsxfun(@ge,[1:m]',0:n-1))
```

Sample run -

```
A =
     1     2     2     2     6
     6     4     8     4     3
     8     5     6     5     4
     7     9     4     2     6
Aout =
     1     2     0     0     0
     6     4     8     0     0
     0     5     6     5     0
     0     0     4     2     6
```

**Approach #2**

If you were working with `tridiag` obtained from [here](http://web.mit.edu/18.06/www/Course-Info/Mfiles/tridiag.m), you could have just done the following for `n x n` sized matrices -

```
Aout = A.*tridiag(1,1,1,n)
```

---

### Edit

With reference to the edited part of the question, this code should work -

```
%// Create regularly shaped all matrices holding variable. 
%// This regularity would be used for cutting into a 3D array in the next step
A = cat(1,NaN(3),a,c,b,d,f,e,g,i,h,j,NaN(3),k,NaN(3),NaN(3));

%// Cut A after every 9 rows
N = 9;
Acut = permute(reshape(A,N,size(A,1)/N,[]),[1 3 2])

%// Create mask that will act as the building unit for L
m = 4;n = 5; 
mask = bsxfun(@le,[0:m-1]',1:n) & bsxfun(@ge,[1:m]',0:n-1)

%// Setup L with ones at places where elements from matrices are top be put
sf = 3; %// scaling factor
L = double(mask(ceil(1/sf:1/sf:size(mask,1)), ceil(1/sf:1/sf:size(mask,2))))

%// Finally, place the elements from matrices into their respective places
L(L==1) = Acut(~isnan(Acut))
```

Comment: I edited my starting post with an example. I don't want to get a tridiagonal matrix of a given matrix. I am trying to create a new tridiagonal matric with random smaller matrices which are given.

Comment: @fYpsE Please check out the edited code at the end. That seems to work for the newly added requirements of the question. Let me know how it goes!

Answer (score 2):

You have to figure out a combination of `trill` and `triu`

```
 a = randi(9,4,5);
 a .* triu(ones(4,5),-1).*tril(ones(4,5),1)

 >>ans =

 4     6     0     0     0
 9     1     7     0     0
 0     8     7     7     0
 0     0     4     1     8
```

And for floating data it will do the same,

```
 a = rand(4,5);
 a .* triu(ones(4,5),-1).*tril(ones(4,5),1)

>>ans =

0.6948    0.4387         0         0         0
0.3171    0.3816    0.4898         0         0
     0    0.7655    0.4456    0.2760         0
     0         0    0.6463    0.6797    0.4984
```

More efficiently (thanks to @Divakar),

```
a.*(triu(ones(4,5),-1) & tril(ones(4,5),1));
```

Or even more simpler (thanks to @LuisMendo),

```
tril(triu(a,-1),1);
```

Comment: You can use booleans too there - `a.*(triu(ones(4,5),-1) & tril(ones(4,5),1))`

Comment: @Divakar, Thanks, So I'll edit the answer (with your permission).

Comment: Sure go ahead please!

Comment: Why not just `tril(triu(a,-1),1)`? No need to multiply by ones

Comment: I guess I didn't explained it good enough. I edited my starting post. Maybe it is more clear now.
Your answer just changes the one matrix I already have to an tridiagonal matrix, doesn't it?